# \beamergotobutton size

Tags: beamer, fontsize

How do I change the default size of the button?

Right now I have a frame looking like this:

```
\documentclass[T]{beamer}

\definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=red}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{WEPRC 2012 Overview}
    \begin{itemize}
    \centering
    \begin{Large}
    \item \hyperlink{PARTICIPANTS}{\beamergotobutton{Participants}} 
    \item \hyperlink{PRESENTERS}{\beamergotobutton{Presenters}}
    \item \hyperlink{KEYNOTESPEAKER}{\beamergotobutton{Keynote Speaker}}
    \item \hyperlink{SPONSOR}{\beamergotobutton{Sponsors}}
    \end{Large} 
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post fully compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine the `button` template and use TikZ to customize the buttons according to your needs; a little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{button}{\tikz
  \node[
  inner xsep=10pt,
  draw=structure!80,
  fill=structure!50,
  rounded corners=4pt]  {\Large\insertbuttontext};}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{WEPRC 2012 Overview}
\begin{itemize}
\item \hyperlink{PARTICIPANTS}{\beamergotobutton{Participants}} 
\item \hyperlink{PRESENTERS}{\beamergotobutton{Presenters}}
\item \hyperlink{KEYNOTESPEAKER}{\beamergotobutton{Keynote Speaker}}
\item \hyperlink{SPONSOR}{\beamergotobutton{Sponsors}}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Font switches are to be used in the form `\Large` (they are commands) with possible grouping: `{\Large...}`, to kkep the change local.

Comment: @Gonzalo I wanted something simple, so I tried ``\setbeamerfont{button}{size=\Huge}`` but while that changes the text inside the button, it doesn't alter the button itself, so I guess there is no one-liner for this one? (one is always reluctant to adding a package for a single feature and looks for class-based solutions as much as possible, having said that I'm a great fan of ``TikZ``)

Comment: @PatrickT Indeed; the size of the button is not easily changed using user hooks. You can see the definition of the button (which, by the way, is built using PGF) in, for example, `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`. You'll notice that the dimensions of the button are hard-coded, so it's simpler to use a user-based modification as the one in my answer. Of course, you can avoid using TikZ and you can use PGF directly (as the class does), if you don't want to load TikZ.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, Thanks! Actually, I guess I've enjoyed tweaking the appearance of the buttons, and have tucked away the code in my customized ``sty`` file, where I shall probably forget it for a while. :-)  I got a reasonably low-profile button with ``\node[inner xsep = 5pt, draw = structure!90, fill = white, rounded corners = 5pt]{\color{structure!90}\tiny\insertbuttontext};}``  together with ``[yshift=7pt,xshift=0pt]``