# How to include an image in between text in beamer?

Tags: graphics

I want to add facebook like action button in front of 2.7 billion below

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Facebook}
\begin{itemize}
\item 2.7 billion \underline{Like actions} 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Do you want to place this instead of the bullet point? Or perhaps use a 'description' to describe images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you like interactive buttons you can use Beamer some control sequences like `\beamergotobutton` and `\hypertarget`. Run `texdoc beamer` and see "11.1 Adding Hyperlinks and Buttons".

On the other hand, instead of use image like icons, may be the `fontawesome` package could be useful, because the thumbs-up icon of this font is simpler, but you avoid messing with external images and you can use behind  many other icons  with a consistent style.

To illustrate this, in the example the buttons of the first slide go to the second or third slide, showing some more icons to show the look & feel of this font. (Compile it with `xelatex` or `lualatex`).

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\geometry{paperheight=1.5in,paperwidth=3.5in}
\usepackage{fontspec,fontawesome}
\usepackage{tikz}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
% custom buttom http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108183/11604
\setbeamertemplate{button}{\tikz
 \node[
  inner xsep=2pt,
  inner ysep=2pt,
  draw=structure!40,
  fill=structure!90,
  rounded corners=4pt]  {\insertbuttontext};} 

\def\FBbutton{\raisebox{-.8ex}{\beamergotobutton{\normalsize\faHandRight}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\faFacebookSign acebook post-injury testing}

\begin{itemize}
\item 1.7 billion \$  
    \only<1>{\hyperlink{wrong}{\FBbutton}} 
    \only<2>{{\textcolor{olive}{\faThumbsDown { \em porca miseria}}}} 
    \only<3>{{\alert{\faThumbsUp\ I'm not greedy}}} 
\item 2.7 billion \$  
    \only<1>{\hyperlink{right}{\FBbutton} \textcolor{gray}{What is better?}}  
    \only<2>{\color{structure}\faThumbsUp\  %
\textcolor{black!40!green}{I liked \faMoney}} 
    \only<3>{\alert{\faThumbsDown\  not fit in the pocket}} 
\end{itemize}

\hypertarget<2>{right}{\faThumbsUp\  %
\textcolor{structure}{Test passed. No neuronal damage.}}
\hypertarget<3>{wrong}{\alert{\faAmbulance\ }%
\textcolor{structure}{ Oh, my God!}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: oh wow....such an innovative answer

Comment: Thumbs up for "porca miseria"

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package (which `beamer` internally loads); for convenience I defined a `\FBLike` command to easily include the image when required:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\FBLike{\includegraphics[height=2ex]{like}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Facebook}
\begin{itemize}
\item 2.7 billion \FBLike 
\item[\FBLike] 2.7 billion \underline{Like actions} 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 2.7 billion \FBLike is what I was looking for. Perfect answer