# List of Icons in Beamer

Tags: beamer, icon

I am relative new to latex. I am preparing a presentation with beamer. I want to create a list of variables, like `C ={a,b,c,d}` but instead of variables I would like to insert people's icons, something like this
[image]

Is there a specific library that provides such icons and enable us to use them as variables? I am guessing tikz will do the work(I noticed tikzpeople package) but I hope there is something simpler.

Thank you.

Comment: simplest is just to use `\includegraphics{..}` for each one getting the people images from whatever source you want for such things

Comment: There is [`tikzducks`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikzducks)...

Comment: @Werner NO!!!!!!

Comment: Related: [Smileys in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3695/5764)

Comment: Ir depends a lot on what kind of icons you will need. For some purpose,  even a font like `fontawesone` could be enough. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/259006/11604.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, well it was that easy, thank you!

Comment: there is even [tikzpeople](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzpeople).

Comment: @vipa Very nice package, highly customisable, I love it!