# Enable go-to button for latex poster

Tags: beamer, posters, navigation

Can I insert such navigation button or go-to button so that when I click the button, the block will show a different block?
[image]

The code for building the go-to button is:

```
\hyperlink{columns}{\beamergotobutton{columns page}}
```

Now I have this block:

```
\begin{block}{Introduction}
\vspace{-20pt}
\heading{Model-assisted design}
\vspace{-20pt}
\begin{outline}
 \1 Assume a model for decision making and pre-tabulate dose transition rules to determine maximum tolerated dose (MTD)
 \1 Example: BOIN design, Keyboard design, etc.
 
\hyperlink{columns}{\beamergotobutton{columns page}}
\end{block}
```

I add the go-to button at the end of the block. If I click the go-to button, I want to replace the block with some new content or a new block, say:

```
\begin{block}{new block}
new contents
\end{block}
```

Can I achieve this kind of effect with the go-to button?

Update:
The answer provided by @Jasper Habicht is exactly what I want. After I apply the code in poster, I cannot place the go-to button till the bottom of this column:

[image]
[image]

The sample code is:

```
\begin{column}{\colwidth}

  \vspace{-20pt}
  \begin{block}{Abstract}

    Abstract content

  \end{block}

    \vspace{-25pt}
    \begin{block}{Introduction}
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \heading{Model-assisted design}
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \begin{outline}
     \1 Assume a model for decision making and pre-tabulate dose transition rules to determine maximum tolerated dose (MTD)
     \1 Example: BOIN design, Keyboard design, etc.
    \end{outline}
     
    
  \end{block}

    \vspace{-25pt}
    
    
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3cm}
    %
    \only<1>{
        \begin{block}{Introduction}<1>\label<1>{first}
        This is the first part of the text.
        \end{block}
    }
    %
    \only<2>{
        \begin{block}{More Stuff}<2>\label<2>{second}
        This is the second part of the text. Which is a bit longer, but because the overlayarea has a fixed height, it doesn't matter.
        \end{block}
    }
    %
    \only<3>{
        \begin{block}{Conclusion}<3>\label<3>{third}
        This is the third part of the text.
        \end{block}
    }
    %
    \end{overlayarea}
    
    \hyperlink{first}{\beamergotobutton{1}}
    \hyperlink{second}{\beamergotobutton{2}}
    \hyperlink{third}{\beamergotobutton{3}}
   
\end{column}
```

`\vfill` didn't work out.

How can I place the go-to button?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you provide some code that we can use? It would help to get to know a bit of your set up.

Comment: To me, a "poster" is a 1m by 1.5m piece of paper showing your work that you stand next to.  Talking about clicking a button in such a thing doesn't make sense.  Are you talking about a beamer presentation instead?  (As Jasper suggests, having provided a bit more code would have made this clearer.)

Comment: @Teepeemm I am trying to make a poster that can be shown electronically, so that speaker can click the screen for different contents within one block.

Comment: You can increase the height of the `overlayarea` by adjusting the second argument which is currently `3cm`. So instead of `\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3cm}`, maybe write `\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{6cm}` or so. This may already help you to shift the buttons downwards.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks! Do you know how to move the button to the right? I enlarge the size of the button following this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108174/beamergotobutton-size, but don't know how to set the buttons to right-hand side.

Comment: Place `\hfill` before `\hyperlink{first}{\beamergotobutton{1}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve exactly, but maybe you can use overlays to replace the contents of the box on different slides. Beamer provides the environment `overlayarea` which has a fixed size that will be the same on each slide. You can place stuff in there which you can assign only to be displayed on the first, second or third slide of the frame. You can then add `\label`s to link to the slides.

So maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3cm}
%
\only<1>{
    \begin{block}{Introduction}<1>\label<1>{first}
    This is the first part of the text.
    \end{block}
}
%
\only<2>{
    \begin{block}{More Stuff}<2>\label<2>{second}
    This is the second part of the text. Which is a bit longer, but because the overlayarea has a fixed height, it doesn't matter.
    \end{block}
}
%
\only<3>{
    \begin{block}{Conclusion}<3>\label<3>{third}
    This is the third part of the text.
    \end{block}
}
%
\end{overlayarea}

\hyperlink{first}{\beamergotobutton{1}}
\hyperlink{second}{\beamergotobutton{2}}
\hyperlink{third}{\beamergotobutton{3}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! This is exactly what I want to achieve, but I don't know how to place the go-to button at the bottom of the column. Please see my latest update in the post!